# Best way to have a persistent in-memory hash in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, in-memory-database

Say I have a table of 100000 cities (id, city) and my application is laid out in a way that I require the id->city mapping for many searches. Running a SQL record for each such translation is prohibitory. Say a search result page displays 1000 records, I don't want to add 1000 SQL queries on top of the existing query.

I've read about the eager loading primitive (:includes) and that doesn't' exactly fit my need. I want to have this table of 100000 cities resident in memory. At present I am trying to avoid something like redis to save myself from one dependency.

Is there a shared memory area where I can shove in this hash table when rails/passenger starts and then all incoming requests can lookup this persistent hash from there.

I believe if I create such an hash in my application_controller, this hash will be initialized every time a request comes in which will make things worse than what I have now ( or will it not ?)

What is the rails way of instantiating a shared persistent memory which all requests can share ?

Comment: Any cache server with sufficient storage space. If not Redis, there's also memcached. You'll need some sort of caching anyway.

Comment: Rails isn't the place to cache that information. Do it with a separate server designed for it. Avoiding dependencies, when those things are designed to do what you need, isn't a good use of your time or your resources. Pick and choose wisely, instead of arbitrarily avoiding something simply because it "wasn't invented here", which is what you're doing.

Comment: the Tin Man - I don't agree with this statement. I think you'd want to consider whether adding an external dependency (and requisite operational overhead) is a good use of your time or not.  If it's a trivial data set relative to his available memory, then using in memory store will fit his needs.

Comment: Rails already relies on a server, the DB, to handle data caching. The problem is, we have no idea what his data objects are, nor his server capability, or whether his DB design is correct (returning 1,000 records shouldn't take 1,000 queries). As is, the question is very nebulous and poorly defined and without that information it's hard to give any sort of usable answer accept that it's possible, but we don't know if it's a good idea.

Comment: @theTinMan The question isn't poorly defined - nor I am trying to use something because it 'wasn't invented here'. The question is a 10,000 foot design question of "Is there a way to avoid redis/external cache if we can fit a relatively small hash somewhere in memory". Its a rails design question. I know about these caches and trade offs etc. What I wanted to avoid is to implement redis and then later come across this nifty rails feature that does the same thing. It seems there isn't any such nifty feature (yet) so looks like external cache it is. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need caching, you're just trying to avoid an external server. I've used Rails' built-in memory store cache solution for large calculations that are globally valid but I don't want to make a roundtrip to an external cache for.

Use and adapt this setting in your environment.
`config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }`

And of course, the [Rails Caching Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memorystore) has all the details.

Comment: 2.5 ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore
This cache store uses Danga's memcached server to provide a centralized cache for your application. Rails uses the bundled dalli gem by default. This is currently the most popular cache store for production websites.

This is great, I think I'll be able to do what I want with rails in built memory store. Thank you